# How can I select something if the Gimbal is in the way?

Tags: modeling, interface

When I'm modeling with the gimbal in view, I frequently cannot select something if the gimbal is in the way:

[image]

Is there a way to select through the gimbal, rather than having to move so the gimbal isn't in the way?

Answer (score 3):

Hide the transform manipulators (click the left icon):

[image: Transform Manipulators]

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Spacebar</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about that, but I was hoping for a hotkey or something because I keep wanting to quickly use the gimbal when I'm modeling & don't want to have to keep hiding & unhiding it. However, if all else fails, maybe I can use the CTRL SPACEBAR. Actually, I'd love it if somehow you could just select through the gimbal, like if it weren't so sensitive, but I don't know how that'd effect selecting it on purpose.
:\

Comment: I think it is fairly common to hide the manipulators and use G,S,R.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using **LMB** for selection, which is not default setting, and can cause such problem, since dragging with LMB is also a gesture for transforming objects.

As CoDEmanX said, you can either temporally hide the manipulator display, or go to **User Preferences** > **Input**, to change the selection button from **Left** to default **Right**.

---

**Edit:**

If you don't think the LMB dragging gesture is commonly used for you, you can also consider to disable it manually:

1. Go to **User Preferences** > **Input**, uncheck the **3D Manipulator** input;
2. Click **Save User Settings**.

[image]

Comment: Well, I had changed the default L & R MBs in my Preferences because my brain wouldn't adapt quickly enough otherwise...that's why I'm using what looks like the wrong MB.

Comment: Well, answer updated. Hope it can help some.